# Parallel coordination failures

Tags: syntax, conjunctions

Consider this sentence:

> You can manipulate lightning, mist, and wind; traffic with air creatures; and are resistant to electricity damage.

This looks at first glance like a perfectly normal conjunction. It reads a bit clunky, but we have no problem understanding the meaning. We have three verb phrases (whether VP, vP, IP/TP… I don't think it matters here, but I could be wrong) being conjoined with an "and" complementing the auxiliary in the same way a single one of them could be. But the third VP *couldn't* be a complement of "can". You can come up with similar examples with NP or PP complements, or complements of P instead of V, etc.<sup>1</sup>

The fact that students are routinely given tests like [this one](https://www.noslangues-ourlanguages.gc.ca/en/quiz/jeu-quiz-parallel-structure-eng) implies that even noticing that something is wrong isn't automatic for native speakers.

So, what's going on here?

1. It's flatly ungrammatical. People produce these sentences because kids today are stupid and lazy and don't speak proper English.<sup>2</sup> And if you think you understand them, well, if you were properly educated, you'd properly fail to understand them. I think this answer is obviously wrong.
2. It's like syllepsis. According to some definitions, this actually *is* syllepsis (and/or zeugma),<sup>3</sup> but as far as I know, theoretical treatments that explain syllepsis use definitions that don't fit this example.<sup>4</sup> But maybe one of those explanations can be broadened to cover all cases of failed parallelism? Something like this: the sentence *is* ungrammatical, but we don't *notice* that until we've already parsed and mostly understood the sentence (or produced it aloud or in writing), at which point all that judgment can do is add the feeling of clunkiness. The problem is that this way seems to contradict how grammar is supposed to work in most theories.<sup>5</sup> Not noticing that your parse required the same verb to be used in two different senses is one thing; not noticing that you couldn't even parse the sentence is very different.
3. This is really a nested coordination: a list of two predicates, one of which is itself a list of two things you can do: [You [[can [manipulate…, traffic…]] and [are resistant…]]]. That certainly parses, and makes sense. And you can even explain why it's clunky: there's a null conjunction on the inner coordination (which is legal but often awkward or ambiguous), and the prosody (in speech) or punctuation (in writing) is misleading.<sup>6</sup> The problem with this interpretation is that I don't think it's what people are actually thinking when they produce and process these sentences; I think we interpret it as a list of three things.
4. The list isn't really the complement to "can", it's a level above that. The actual parse is something like [You [[can manipulate…]; [_ traffic…]; and [are resistant…]]], where the "can" fills the gap in the second coordinate, and there is no gap to fill in the third one, and that's fine.<sup>7</sup> This works, but feels fishy for some reason I can't put my finger on.
5. It's ungrammatical, but we routinely repair ungrammatical utterances into grammatical sentences, and don't consciously notice it in many cases. Which is fine, but… what's the grammatical sentence we repair this into? (And, if the answer is the one from (3) or (4), why do we even need to evoke repair here?)

I'm having a hard time coming up with examples that would rule out possibilities 3 and 4, but it seems like they probably exist.

And maybe there's a better explanation than any of these.

---

<sub>1. I opened up a stack of textbooks and RPG manuals to random pages and quickly found multiple examples. I chose this one because it's obviously not a part-of-speech problem: "are resistant to electricity damage" is a VP/IP/TP, just not one that can come after the auxiliary "can", and removing the tense doesn't "correct" it, but instead ruins the meaning. Unfortunately, I stupidly didn't take notes on where the examples came from—but on further searching, I think I've found it. Almost exactly this sentence appears in the Pathfinder core rules PDF (page 41), but with commas instead of semicolons. So I presumably got it from the printed book with the same rules (different revision, so maybe they changed the punctuation at some point to match house style guides). Anyway, the sentence is describing the "granted powers" of clerics who specialize in air, and it clearly means that the cleric *is* resistant to electricity, not that he might be, or can choose to be, or anything like that.</sub>

<sub>2. And if it's even more common in professional formal writing than colloquial speech, well, professional writers must be stupid kids too. And if most copy editors don't correct it, they all need to be fired. And if it's been common for centuries, we need to get Doctor Who off the air so kids today can't use time machines to ruin our language retroactively.</sub>

<sub>3. Most dictionaries say they're synonyms, but most usage guides, etc. disagree—and then give completely contradictory distinctions. "Syllepsis is semantic, zeugma is syntactic" and "syllepsis is grammatical, zeugma is logical" are nearly opposites. And then there's the Oxford guide and their literary dictionary, which say that *all* parallel coordination is zeugma, and syllepsis is zeugma gone wrong, with a part-of-speech mismatch. The last does seem to be what Johnson meant by "zeugma", but nobody but Oxford seems to use it that way in the 20th century and beyond. Anyway, I don't want to get into that discussion here.</sub>

<sub>4. In particular, I mean explanations for the pun-like cases where you use a different sense of the same governing verb, or cases like Thurber's "I was losing weight, my grip, and my mind". One explanation is that these problems don't come up during parsing, only during later stages of… whatever happens in semantics, or maybe even after. So we understand the sentence, then notice that the incongruity, which makes the sentence strikes us as funny or powerful (or, when poorly done, clunky). That explanation doesn't immediately seem to work for "You can are resistant to electrical damage", which is just flat-out ungrammatical, not grammatical-but-requiring-a-conflicting-reading.</sub>

<sub>5. Not just Chomskyan theories. (In fact, they can just say this is a performance rather than competence problem, or that whatever's going on here is part of the periphery, not the core…) It's just as bad for constraint PSGs, CxGs, etc. Any theory that says that we understand sentences by building (or unifying) a parse tree is going to have trouble explaining how we can understand this sentence even though you can't build a valid tree for it.</sub>

<sub>6. The processing-cost factor of holding both the outer and inner sub-trees in your head until you get to the end of the sentence and can finally disambiguate things could also contribute to clunkiness.</sub>

<sub>7. Possibly not using a gap when you have something in position to fill the gap is legal but marked, which is part of what makes this clunky?</sub>

Comment: I'd say ungrammaticality is out -- this type of coordination is very common in all registers of English, probably more common than the logically "correct" type with another *and* between the first two items. It's standard English.

Comment: It's a matter of Conjunction Reduction.  I don't see the problem (but, then, I'm an atmosphere).

Comment: You find that example sentence comprehensible? I'm not being snide — I actually don't know what it means or is referring to.

Comment: @TKR Of course; that's why I said ungrammaticality was obviously wrong. The question is, how is it grammatical? You seem to be suggesting that it's #3: we interpret it as a nested coordination that's just missing the extra "and" and punctuated/pronounced wrong. But I don't think that's right; I think we interpret it as a flat list of three things. And I'm looking for either examples that can distinguish the two, or a paper that makes the case one way or the other, or something more than my vague feeling.

Comment: @GregLee How is this CR? What are the non-constituents being coordinated here? Are you suggesting something like #4, except that the second coordinate is incomplete and reconstructed with the "can" from the first coordinate?

Comment: @LukeSawczak Yes, it's perfectly comprehensible. Is your problem maybe the use of "traffic" as a verb, or the fact that the first coordinate is so long and complex? What about "You can eat your cereal, drink your coffee, and have plenty of time"? (That one seems a lot clunkier to me, but it avoids both potential problems. If that helps you, I can try to find a better example and edit it into the question.)

Comment: @LukeSawczak If you find that example just as incomprehensible, it means that three things are true: (1) you can eat your cereal, (2) you can drink your coffee, and (3) you have plenty of time. Meanwhile, assuming you're not a native speaker, the fact that it's _not_ comprehensible to L2 speakers may be a useful hint, but it may also just mean that you learned English syntax from a prescriptivist textbook that just didn't teach you to interpret it the same way L1 speakers do.

Comment: I just tried to derive your example by CR but couldn't do it.  I guess it should have been " ... and be resistant ..."

Comment: @GregLee Yeah, _that_ could be a simple matter of CR—but that also has a different meaning: "You can be resistant" doesn't just mean "you are resistant", but I think this sentence (surely to the writer, and probably to any native reader) does.

Comment: @abarnert I am a native speaker, and an editor. :) I do understand it now, and the issue was indeed "traffic" as a verb, which is likely due to its mostly taking a direct object ("human trafficking") or the particle "in" ("trafficking in drugs"), whereas "with" suggests a nominal form: "Accused of traffic with the enemy." That said, I wouldn't confidently rule it out. I just got garden-path'd so hard that by the time I got to "are", I didn't actually realize the subject was still "you" and was wondering what else it could be. I guess that goes to show how confusing malformed parallels can be.

Comment: @LukeSawczak OK, that makes sense. For that matter, how often do you see "air creatures" outside of D&D-speak? So this probably wasn't the best example; sorry. Meanwhile, are you a BritEng speaker, by any chance? Because I think "to traffic with" is more common in AmEng, and in fact your example would more likely be written "accused of trafficking with the enemy" in a US newspaper.

Comment: @abarnert Canadian English, so it's a wash :) Hmm, "trafficking with" does sound natural. Maybe it's the participle/gerund. Actually, now that I've parsed your example correctly, "traffic with" doesn't sound odd there either... not sure of my instincts here. And yeah, "air creatures" does feel like an odd collocation outside of fantasy games.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Actually, I can imagine "air creatures" being used euphemistically by airlines and/or government bureaucrats: the airplane didn't murder a cute little birdie by sucking it into the jets; it had an encounter with an air creature… :)

Comment: @abarnert Or with an AAAH, or adverse animate airborne hazard :p

Comment: Do 3 & 4 make different predictions about the behavior of this construction? (If not, I'm not sure how meaningful the difference between them is.)

Comment: @TKR That's exactly the question. With this example, the difference between a nested coordination and a flat one is so subtle that I don't trust my (or anyone else's) judgment too far on it. I'm hoping that _different_ examples will make it a lot clearer—either 4 will clearly not work, or 3 will give the blatantly wrong interpretation, or something. What kind of example? Maybe a different kind of semantic difference? Or a node attached to the right of the coordination? I'm not sure; that's why I'm asking…

Comment: For me (native speaker of BrEng) 3 captures it perfectly. Why do you say *I don't think it's what people are actually thinking when they produce and process these sentences; I think we interpret it as a list of three things*? I interpret it as a list of two things, one of which is subdivided.

Comment: I'm not seeing much of a difference between 3 and 4. It's the fact that there is no gap that *can* could fill that tips us off to the fact that the third element is not part of the complement of *can*. The more obvious this is, the easier I think it would be to parse first time (my initial reaction was that *are* should be *be*, whereas if the modal changed, as in *you can ... ; ... ; and must ...*, there would be no danger of that). 4 seems like an explanation of how 3 might be implemented than a genuinely different analysis.

Comment: I haven’t read through all the comments, but I can’t see how ungrammaticality can be ruled out. The sentence is **completely** ungrammatical and meaningless to me. I have absolutely no idea what the third ‘part’ (after the last semicolon) is supposed to mean or refer to, nor do I have any idea what manipulating traffic with air creatures is supposed to mean. It’s complete gibberish to me. Only after reading your point 3 did I manage to resolve it into something that at least grammatically makes sense (though semantically I still have no idea what’s going on).

Comment: I haven't either, and just chanced on this. I suggest one treat it as a weak boundary for _can_, which fribbles away when you get to the third one. Those semicolons ground the modal scope.

Comment: The sentences in your link are not at all like this invented one of  yours. So.... I see no simple fix here, including the fact the semantics of it are iffy. The first thing that came to mind was: to traffic air creatures [DO], no with.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue here concerns the following three parses of the instances of conjunction in the example sentence:

(1) a.  You [can [manipulate [lightning], [mist], and [wind]]; [traffic with air creatures]]; and [are resistant to electricity damage].

(1) b.  You [can manipulate [lightning], [mist], and [wind]]; [{can} traffic with air creatures]; and [are resistant to electricity damage].

(1) c.  You [can manipulate [lightning], [mist], and [wind]]; [traffic with air creatures]; and [are resistant to electricity damage].

The parse in (1a) corresponds to the third possibility given in the question (Possibility 3), and the parse in (1b) corresponds to my interpretation of the fourth possibility in the question (Possibility 4). The parse in (1c) is yet another potential analysis. Of these three parses, I believe that the one in (1a) is best, hence I agree with the first comment (by TKR). Note that the parse in (1c) can be immediately rejected because it does not allow for the the preferred reading of the sentence, which is such that the modal *can* scopes over the conjunct *traffic with air creatures*.

The parse in (1a) is an instance of nested conjunction that is three layers deep (i.e. three distinct instances of conjunction). The intermediate instance of conjunction is asyndetic, meaning that *and* has simply been omitted. Note in this regard that inserting *and* between *wind* and *traffic* results in a sentence with the same interpretation:

(1)     aˈ. You [can [manipulate [lightning], [mist], and [wind]]; **and** [traffic with air creatures]]; and [are resistant to electricity damage].

The advantage that the parse in (1a) has over the parse in (1b) is that in order for the former to work, one can assume a special type of asyndeton, asyndeton being a widely acknowledged and accepted type of conjunction (e.g. *Veni, vidi, vici*). In order for the parse in (1b) to work, in contrast, one needs to posit an elided *can*, as indicated there with *{can}*. In other words, to make the parse in (1b) work so that the resulting conjuncts are appropriately parallel and *can* scopes over *traffic with air creatures*, one has to reach to ellipsis; one assumes that an instance of *can* has been elided in such a manner that only two instances of conjunction are present (instead of three) and the greatest of the two consists of three finite VP conjuncts.

Examples of conjunction (and coordination more generally) similar to the one discussed here are examined in the following paper:

http://web.stanford.edu/group/cslipublications/cslipublications/HPSG/2004/beavers-sag.pdf

See examples (6a-c) therein in particular. The example (6a) is reproduced here as (2a):

(2) a. Jan travels to Rome tomorrow, to Paris on Friday, and will fly to Tokyo on Sunday.

This example contains an added twist. The coordinated strings *to Rome tomorrow* and *to Paris on Friday* are NOT constituents, hence such cases are known as instances of non-constituent coordination (NCC). I would parse the coordinate structures in this example as follows:

(2) b. Jan [travels [to Rome tomorrow], [to Paris on Friday]], and [will fly to Tokyo on Sunday].

This parse also assumes nested asyndetic conjunction; the conjunction *and* has been omitted from between *tomorrow* and *to*.

Beavers and Sag, the authors of the paper linked to above, argue for an approach to such cases in terms of ellipsis. They would hence advocate a parse for the sentence in the question along the lines shown in (1b) above (Possibility 4), where *can* has been elided. In doing so, they can also overcome standard cases of NCC of the following sort:

(3)     Sam [saw you today] and [{saw} me yesterday].

Assuming ellipsis as indicated with *{saw}*, the conjuncts become finite VPs, and as such, they are constituents. The problem with this sort of analysis, however, is that it makes incorrect predictions about the preferred reading in other cases, e.g.

(4) a.  Sam gave no girl flowers today and chocolates yesterday.

The analysis that Beavers and Sag would likely prefer in this case would assume ellipsis along the following lines:

(4) b.  Sam [gave no girl flowers today] and [{gave no girl} chocolates yesterday].

The conjuncts are now again finite VP constituents. The problem with this type of analysis is that the reading it should have does not match the actual reading of (4a). The reading of (4a) has the negation *no* scoping over both conjuncts (¬(p ∧ q)), whereas the reading that should correspond to the parse in (4b) would have two negations (¬p ∧ ¬q).

In sum, I believe the parse in (1a) is better than the parse in (2b), and it is certainly better than the parse in (1c). I therefore view Possibility 3 in the question as the best analysis. The problem with the parse in (1b) is that it requires ellipsis, where this ellipsis would result in incorrect readings in certain other cases. The advantage of the parse in (1a) is that it is simpler; it merely requires that one acknowledge a particular type of asyndetic conjunction, whereby asyndetic conjunction is an easily observable and accepted type of coordination more generally.

Comment: +1 Thanks for link to B&S